# 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)

Tags: vue.js, nginx, tcp, nuxt.js, digital-ocean

I have been running around this problem since many weeks and I hope this comes to an end here.
I have created droplet and uploaded my nuxt js(universal) in directory named /var/www/chautarisaccos.com/nuxt and below is the configuration I made in file /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/chautarisaccos.com/nuxt/.nuxt/dist/server;

        
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name chautarisaccos.com www.chautarisaccos.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

when I goto http://chautarisaccos.com I am getting 502 bad gateway error. What could be the reason please help me.
Below is the result when I run "netstat -plant"

```
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 157.245.102.182:22      103.225.244.4:25321     ESTABLISHED -                   
tcp        0      0 157.245.102.182:80      94.182.176.136:8527     ESTABLISHED -                   
tcp        0      0 157.245.102.182:22      103.225.244.4:25327     ESTABLISHED -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::33060                :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

Comment: just to make sure you have a link into sites-enabled?

Comment: @Estradiaz yes there is